# Understanding the execution of DataFrame in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, pandas-groupby

I am new to python and i want to understand how the execution takes place in a DataFrame. let's try this with an example from the dataset found in the kaggle.com(**Titanic: Machine Learning from Disaster**). I wanted to **replace the NaN value with the mean() for the respective sex**. ie. the NaN value for Men should be replaced by the mean of the mens age and vice versa. now i achieved this by using this line of code

```
_data['new_age']=_data['new_age'].fillna(_data.groupby('Sex')['Age'].transform('mean'))
```

my question is, while executing the code, how does the line knows that this particular row belongs to male and the NaN value should be replaced by the **male mean()** and female value should be replaced by the **female mean()**.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of **`groupby` + `transform`**. When you group with an aggregation that returns a scalar per group a normal `groupby` collapses to a single row for each unique grouping key.

```
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sex': list('MFMMFFMMFM'),
                   'Age': np.random.choice([1, 10, 11, 13, np.NaN], 10)},
                   index=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))
df.groupby('Sex')['Age'].mean()

#Sex
#F    10.5                # One F row
#M    11.5                # One M row
#Name: Age, dtype: float64
```

Using `transform` will broadcast this result back to the original index based on the group that row belonged to.

```
df.groupby('Sex')['Age'].transform('mean')

#A    11.5  # Belonged to M
#B    10.5  # Belonged to F
#C    11.5  # Belonged to M
#D    11.5
#E    10.5
#F    10.5
#G    11.5
#H    11.5
#I    10.5
#J    11.5
#Name: Age, dtype: float64
```

To make it crystal clear, I'll assign the transformed result back, and now you can see how `.fillna` gets the correct mean.

```
df['Sex_mean'] = df.groupby('Sex')['Age'].transform('mean')
```

---

```
  Sex   Age  Sex_mean
A   M  13.0      11.5
B   F   NaN      10.5  # NaN will be filled with 10.5
C   M  11.0      11.5
D   M   NaN      11.5  # NaN will be filled with 11.5
E   F   NaN      10.5  # Nan will be filled with 10.5
F   F  10.0      10.5
G   M  11.0      11.5
H   M  11.0      11.5
I   F  11.0      10.5
J   M   NaN      11.5  # Nan will be filled with 11.5
```